# Encoding of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, encoding

I have a string S="Test" in Python. I want to encode the string into CP1256, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-2, ISO-8859-6, ISO-8859-15 and Window-1252 formats. How can I do the encoding of the string into the mentioned formats?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I tried for UTF-8, UTF-16 and ASCII encoding which was being encoded without any error, but i was facing problem in case of the mentioned encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why Slava Bacherikov deleted his answer, but it was the right answer, so I'll repeat it with more detail.

---

[`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) is exactly what you want:

> Return an encoded version of the string as a `bytes` object. Default encoding is `'utf-8'`. *errors* may be given to set a different error handling scheme. The default for errors is `'strict'`, meaning that encoding errors raise a [`UnicodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#UnicodeError). Other possible values are `'ignore'`, `'replace'`, `'xmlcharrefreplace'`, `'backslashreplace'` and any other name registered via [`codecs.register_error()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error), see section [Codec Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes). For a list of possible encodings, see section [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

If you follow that link to Standard Encodings, you'll see a nice table that shows you the names to use for each of these (you can use either the main codec name, or any of the aliases).

So:

```
encoded_bytes = [S.encode(codec) for codec in
                 ('cp1256', 'iso-8859-1', 'iso-8859-2', 'iso-8859-6', 
                  'iso-8859-15', 'windows-1252')]
```

---

While you *could* use [`codecs.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode) as the other answers suggest, there's really no good reason to do so, and one good reason not to: `str.encode` enforces the fact that you're calling it on a `str` object, and using a codec that translates `str` to `bytes`; you'll get an exception if you accidentally use it on an already-encoded `bytes` or a `list` or something.

---

All of the above is assuming you're using Python 3. If you're using Python 2, a `str` is already encoded. So, if you can start with a `unicode` object, like `u"Test"` instead of `"Test"`, do that; if not, you will want to `decode` it first. Unfortunately, Python 2 won't enforce that; if you call `str.encode` it will actually decode it with `sys.getdefaultencoding`, which will usually be ASCII, which will lead to silly errors.

Answer (score 0):

its what that [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#module-codecs)  module is for :

```
codecs.encode(S,'CP1256')
```

Comment: Why use `codecs.encode(S)` instead of just `S.encode`?

Answer (score -1):

Just use the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module

```
import codecs
codecs.encode("hello", "iso-8859-6")
```

If you want to first check if python is aware of a certain encoding format just use

```
format_name = "iso-8859-6"
try:
    codecs.lookup(format_name)
except LookupError:
    print "Encoding {} can't be found".format(format_name)
```